# Sum between rows based on selected criteria (Google Spreadsheet)

Tags: google-sheets

everybody

[image]
I am attaching the spreadsheet with an example & explanation:
I was able to sum from start to some specific value, however
I want to sum up values between 2 voluntarily selected rows based on set criteria.

[spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o97fWYZRwXnqA7eTzEHdN11PsFDeTcApRtC2oqVJBrU/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic non-array formula solution:

```
=sum(index(B:B,match(C8,A:A,0)):index(B:B,match(C9,A:A,0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an approximation using [Custom Functions:](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

```js
/**
 * Sum values based on criteria (only valid for 2 dimensional)
 * @param {Range} The 2 dimensional range
 * @param {string} A comma separated criteria
 * @return Sum based on criteria
 * @customfuncion
 */
function SUMCRITERIA(range, criteria) {
  criteria = criteria.split(',').map((letter) => letter.toUpperCase())
  return (range.reduce((pr, current) => {
    return criteria.includes(current[0].toUpperCase()) ? pr + current[1] : pr
  }, 0))
}
```

The function simply checks that the values included in the criteria are part of the left hand side of the range, if so, it adds them.

To add this function `Extensions > Apps Script` and copy paste inside. And then, use as normal:

[image: Using example]